# Apply strong style to number only with Rails pluralize helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have this:

```
<%= link_to biscuits_path do %>
<strong> <%= pluralize @biscuit.count, t('biscuits') %> </strong>
<%= end %>
```

the result is a link like:

```
<a href="/en/biscuits"> <strong> 2 Biscuits </strong></a>
```

I want a link with strong only in the number, something like:

```
<a href="/en/biscuits"> <strong> 2 </strong> Biscuits </a>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is easier and clearer to use `String` pluralize from `ActiveSupport` core extensions:

```
<%= link_to biscuits_path do %>
  <strong><%= @biscuit.size %></strong> <%= "biscuit".pluralize(@biscuit.size)%>
<% end %>
```

Also, you do not need `<%= end %>`. `<% end %>` is fine.

Comment: Note: `String#pluralize` didn't start taking an optional count argument until Rails 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same results by doing the following.

```
<%= link_to biscuits_path do %>
  <strong> <%= @biscuit.size %> </strong> <%= (@biscuit.size > 1) ? 'biscuit'.pluralize : 'biscuit' %>
<%= end %>
```

Also, another thing i noticed, you're passing 'biscuits' as a second argument to pluralize. I believe this should be 'biscuit'. I.e. according to the Rails documentation, the singular term of the word is passed as a second argument.

```
pluralize(count, singular, plural = nil)
```

EDIT: noticed a bug. Fixed it now!

Comment: Sorry but I does not works for me. does not recognize the number, if one or more units. So always pluralized the text. The problem is that if one unit on the counter also pluralized the text equally, therefore it is wrong.

Comment: @hypperrjas. I'm sorry for the mistake. It should only be pluralized if the number is greater than 1.

Comment: Thank you your fix its good but the Pedro nascimento fix, is more elegant and simple! Thank you